# HTTP Polling using `setInterval()` called every 1 sec instead of the mentioned interval

Tags: javascript, angular, setinterval

I have a requirement in my Ionic 4 application where I need to make an API call every 20 seconds. When I use `setInterval()` for it, the API is hit every 1 sec instead of 20 sec. Here is my code, may I know what went wrong?

my **.ts** file

```js
getApiData(){
  this.http.get('https://kairavforex.com/api/libor_rate/',{},{'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': "Token" + " " +  this.authToken})
    .then(data=>{
      this.getData=JSON.parse(data.data).results;      
    })
  this.repeatInterval();
}

repeatInterval(){
   this.rateTimer=setInterval(() => { 
     this.getApiData(); 
  }, 20000);   
}
```

Comment: With this setup you definitely don't want `setInterval` but `setTimeout`

Comment: everytime you call `repeatInterval` it creates another interval, so after 20 sec you'll have 2 intervals, then 4 then 8 and so on

Comment: `repeatInterval = () => {clearTimeout(this.rateTimer); this.rateTimer=setTimeout(this.getApiData, 20000);}`

Comment: Just in case it's called elsewhere - I also use setTimeout intead of interval

Comment: You should also consider, do you want the next API call to happen 20s after the last completed or started? Eg: if the API call takes 5s to return a response should the next call happen in 15s or 20s?

Answer (score 0):

call getApiData in repeatInterval and make as IIFE the repeatInterval

```
getApiData(){
    this.http.get('https://kairavforex.com/api/libor_rate/',{},{'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': "Token" + " " +  this.authToken})
      .then(data=>{
       this.getData=JSON.parse(data.data).results;      
      })
  }

(repeatInterval(){
     this.rateTimer=setInterval(() => { 
       this.getApiData(); 
    }, 20000);   
  })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` functions, you could try to use RxJS [`repeat`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/repeat), [`delay`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/delay) and [`takeUntil`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/takeUntil) (or [`takeWhile`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/takeWhile) depending on your requirement) operators to poll an end-point continuously. Try the following

Some Service

```js
stopPolling$ = new Subject();

getApiData(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(
    'https://kairavforex.com/api/libor_rate/',
    {},
    {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': "Token" + " " +  this.authToken}
  ).pipe(
    tap(data => this.getData = JSON.parse(data.data).results),
    delay(20000),               // <-- poll frequency
    repeat(),                   // <-- poll till `stopPolling$` emits
    takeUntil(stopPolling$)     // <-- emit `stopPolling$` to stop polling
  );
}

stopPollingApi() {
  this.stopPolling$.next();
  this.stopPolling$.complete();
}
```

Some component

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.someService.getApiData().subscribe(    // <-- will start polling
    res => { },
    err => { }
  );
}

someOtherFunc() {               // <-- call this function to stop polling
  if(someCondition) {
    this.someService.stopPollingApi();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by clearing the SetInterval before starting with a new interval in order to avoid interval duplication.

```
getApiData(){
    this.http.get('https://kairavforex.com/api/libor_rate/',{},{'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': "Token" + " " +  this.authToken})
      .then(data=>{
       this.getData=JSON.parse(data.data).results;      
      })
      this.repeatInterval();
  }

  
  repeatInterval(){
    clearInterval(this.rateTimer);
    this.rateTimer=setInterval(() => { 
      this.getApiData(); 
   }, 20000); 
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

First try like this..

```js
var rateTimer;
rateTimer = setInterval(() => {
  console.log("Hello"); 
}, 5000);
```